# Frame _ Current property cannot be animated 2

Tags: materials

I asked this question before and somehow it got closed. so I will try again. I was following along with this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juXVkgguQGo .
at about 11:30 he click "I" and make an key but when I do the same thing I get an error saying  Frame _ Current property cannot be animated . My question is why? it works for him. [image]

Is there any other information you need to help just asked. but IDK what he is during differently than me.

I just want the Cylinder to chance color, like the guys does in the video ...
I do not know why this question was close before...

Comment: Your previous question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163340/frame-current-property-cannot-be-animated was closed because it lacked detail. Rather than open a new one you can edit the old  question as was suggested on more than one occasion. [(with a link that opens your old question in "edit mode")](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/163340/edit)  On most occasions doing so  leads to the question being re-opened.  Please don't instead ask a new question with those edits.  Please read the help documentation on asking questions.

Comment: Use the edit link at the bottom of your original post to add more information or document your progress or fails. Also read: [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: What more information do you need ? I really Do not understand. I post the youtube video I am following. I post the goal I am trying to get. I post a picture of what I have. What more information do you need ?

Comment: When you press I to insert a keyframe, your mouse has  to be hoovering exactly over the property you want to animate. Which is exactely the property?

Comment: Josh Thanks that helped a lot. it is working now. sorry, I am new to Blender and I did not know you have to hove over the property.

Comment: How do I mark Josh's comment as the answer ?